# Pandas read_csv with incorrect header delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file, say test.csv and looks like this

```
Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 |
1      | 2      | 3      |      |      |    6
```

If I open up the csv in notepad++ or text, it shows up like this

```
Data 1, Data 2, Data 3
1,2,3,,,6

instead of

Data 1, Data 2, Data 3, ,,
1,2,3,,,6
```

I get an error using pandas.read_csv because my rows have more columns than declared in my header row.  Are there ways to find the maximum number of columns of the entire CSV?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to read in the csv? If you have no header for given rows it should still read in and the columns will be named 'Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1' etc.

Comment: Does `read_csv` have some sort of `skip_header` parameter?

Comment: @Denver The 'Unnamed: 1' only shows up if it sees empty headers, as shown above in the second example with the extra ",,," indicating empter but existing headers.  In my case, I have NO headers, and errors out when trying to read more than x columns

Comment: @hpaulj Should have stated the example above is a simplified version.  It does have a skip header, but in my case the first 200 rows have x columns, then row 201 has x+5 columns

Comment: Read the docs to see what options it has for handing rows with different numbers of columns and/or missing values.  A proper csv has a consistent number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

My proposition is to:

- skip the title row,
- specify your own list of column names.

So the code should be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), skiprows=1,
    names=['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6'])
```

A detail to consider is how should be represented empty cells.

The default behaviour of *read_csv* is to treat them as *NaN*, but
the downside is then that such columns are coerced to *float*.

Another possibility is to pass `na_filter=False` parameter and then:

- such empty strings are represented "as is" (as an empty string),
- but columns with these values are this time coerced to *object*,
  because *string* cells are intermixed with *int*.

Note also that the format of your title row is corrupted in one more
detail. The source of problem are spaces after commas:
They become the initial part of the next column name.

So even if you had just 3 columns of data, the column names would be:

```
['Data 1', ' Data 2', ' Data 3']
```

(note the leading spaces). So this is yet another reason to skip the
title row.